# Unable to open sub menu on li mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open a sub menu on the right side of current menu on on mouse-over of the first `li ie` photographs.

I am unable to do this.Please help.Any help will be appreciated.

I have sub menu like this-

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Progress</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="id2" onclick="Reports(this.id)" style="color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin:0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap">photographs</span></li>
        <li id="id3" onclick="Reports(this.id)" style="color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin:0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap">CORP</span></li>
        <li id="id4" onclick="Reports(this.id)" style="color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin:0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap">PSU</span></li>
        <li id="id5" onclick="Reports(this.id)" style="color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin:0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap">SSA</span></li>
        <li id="id6" onclick="Reports(this.id)" style="color:white;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin:0px 5px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap">RMSA</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the css i am using-

```
.sub-menu {
    max-height: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    /*  top: 100%;*/
    transition: max-height .5s .2s;
    -moz-transition: max-height .5s .2s;
    -o-transition: max-height .5s .2s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height .5s .2s;
}
```

Comment: Is the submenu opened on click or on hover? Also, `max-height : 0` on `.sub-menu` means that the element will be hidden. What have you tried? Is the parent `li` in relative position?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li a").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").fadeIn();
});

$("li a").mouseout(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to set the listener in HTML, like you're doing with `onclick`, then the attribute you're looking for is `onmouseover`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` selector on the parent

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/xbybso79/))

```
li:hover .sub-menu {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Also, in the demo I've taken the liberty of moving the inline styles into css declarations. Inline styles should be avoided if at all possible

Comment: @hmble.rumble the sub-menu on mosueover of progress is already appearing,I want another sub menu to be opened on the mouse hover of first li i.e. photographs,to appear(it contain few <li>s)